# Export Gridview to Excel in ASP.net with EPPlus

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I'm trying to export datas from my gridview to an Excel file.

I've tried with the EPPlus library but it only print the first page of the gridview even when I'm disabling paging at the beginning of the algorithm.

Here is the code using EPPlus:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridData.xlsx");

cgvReferentiel.AllowPaging = false;    // here I'm disabling paging

if (cgvReferentiel.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    var dtb = new DataTable();

    // Creating table headers
    dtb.Columns.Add("PAYS", typeof(string));
    dtb.Columns.Add("SOCIETE", typeof(string));
    dtb.Columns.Add("SECTION", typeof(string));
    dtb.Columns.Add("MATRICULE", typeof(string));
    dtb.Columns.Add("NOM(S)", typeof(string));
    dtb.Columns.Add("PRENOM(S)", typeof(string));
    dtb.Columns.Add("IDENTIFIANT", typeof(string));
    dtb.Columns.Add("SOURCE", typeof(string));
    dtb.Columns.Add("TYPE", typeof(string));
    dtb.Columns.Add("DATE D'ARCHIVAGE", typeof(string));

    // Adding rows content
    foreach (GridViewRow row in cgvReferentiel.Rows)
    {
        var pays = row.Cells[0].Text;
        var societe = row.Cells[1].Text;
        var section = row.Cells[2].Text;
        var matricule = row.Cells[3].Text;
        var nom = row.Cells[4].Text;
        var prenom = row.Cells[5].Text;
        var identifiant = row.Cells[6].Text;
        var source = row.Cells[7].Text;
        var type = row.Cells[8].Text;
        var date = row.Cells[9].Text;

        dtb.Rows.Add(pays, societe, section, matricule, nom, prenom, identifiant, source, type, date);
    }

    // Writing the excel file
    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        ExcelWorksheet wsDt = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Historique");
        wsDt.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dtb, true, TableStyles.Light20);
        wsDt.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

        Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
    }

    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Comment: @VDWWD I've tried it but i'm facing another issue. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out what was the matter. I needed to bind gridview rows after disabling paging with:

```
cgvReferentiel.DataBind();
```